# How to get local IP in Flutter Web

Tags: flutter, ip-address, flutter-web

I'm trying to get the local IP address in a Flutter Web app. Searching the internet I came around this package: `get_ip` 0.4.0 - it states it is working under web.

I have this function:

```
Future<void> initPlatformState() async {
    print("Test");
    String ipAddress;
    // Platform messages may fail, so we use a try/catch PlatformException.
    try {
      ipAddress = await GetIp.ipAddress;
    } on PlatformException {
      ipAddress = 'Failed to get ipAddress.';
    } on Exception {
      print("Exception");
    }

    print("Ip: $ipAddress");
  }
```

and I call it in `initState` of `main.dart`.

The console just has the output `Test`, it does not output the IP or `Exception`.

Has someone already used this package? Would there be an other way for a web app to get the local IP?

(I'm using MacOS)

Answer (score 7):

The [get_ip](https://pub.dev/packages/get_ip) package states that it supports Android/iOS.
So,instead of using the package,you can directly interact with [ipify](https://www.ipify.org/) endpoint.
Check out their API documentation for more!

```js
Future<String> getIP() async {
  try {
    const url = 'https://api.ipify.org';
    var response = await http.get(url);
    if (response.statusCode == 200) { 
      print(response.body);
      return response.body;
    } else {
      print(response.body);
      return null;
    }
  } catch (exception) {
    print(exception);
    return null;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm Using ip_geolocation_api Package for getting an IP address and it is working as expected

```
  String text = '';
  GeolocationData geolocationData;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    this.getIp();
  }

  Future<void> getIp() async {
    geolocationData = await GeolocationAPI.getData();
    if (geolocationData != null) {
      setState(() {
        text = geolocationData.ip;
        print(text);
      });
    }
  }
```

Now You have IP in the text Variable.