# How in flutter web get client ip?

Tags: flutter, dart

I need just user ip, who browse my website on flutter. It is so simple in php(without balancer) just $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] but can't find same function in flutter web. I can create php file and make additional request, but may be is exist more fast solution.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61574652/flutter-web-getting-local-ip

Comment: Salim, It is not what I want. I need ip address without additional requests. On low level langs it is possible. Server anyway have this var and in theory I can use it instantly. Slow internet users don't need to wait it. And it is little security risk, user can inject this ip address in js request. And use it for spam in my app for example.